# Almost identical Spring Rest request return different responses, how to understand Spring trace?

Tags: rest, spring

I have two almost identical controllers connecting to two different JPA Spring data repositories. The JPA request work correctly, been tested.

I have other request on the same server that works perfectly. Why two different requests that are almost identical don't response with a correct response?

How I can find tips from Spring trace about this problem? I get a `Status not found` for a request:

```
type Status report

message /hospital/EditWard/HOSP1/

description The requested resource is not available.
```

In the console I see this trace:

```
2015-03-06 11:45:16,686 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' processing GET request for [/hospital/EditWard/HOSP1/]
2015-03-06 11:45:16,686 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' processing GET request for [/hospital/EditWard/HOSP1/]
2015-03-06 11:45:16,687 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] - Looking up handler method for path /EditWard/HOSP1/
2015-03-06 11:45:16,687 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] - Looking up handler method for path /EditWard/HOSP1/
2015-03-06 11:45:16,689 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] - Did not find handler method for [/EditWard/HOSP1/]
2015-03-06 11:45:16,689 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] - Did not find handler method for [/EditWard/HOSP1/]
2015-03-06 11:45:16,690 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping] - Matching patterns for request [/EditWard/HOSP1/] are [/**]
2015-03-06 11:45:16,690 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping] - Matching patterns for request [/EditWard/HOSP1/] are [/**]
2015-03-06 11:45:16,690 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping] - URI Template variables for request [/EditWard/HOSP1/] are {}
2015-03-06 11:45:16,690 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping] - URI Template variables for request [/EditWard/HOSP1/] are {}
2015-03-06 11:45:16,690 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping] - Mapping [/EditWard/HOSP1/] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler@23c3853d] and 1 interceptor
2015-03-06 11:45:16,690 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping] - Mapping [/EditWard/HOSP1/] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler@23c3853d] and 1 interceptor
2015-03-06 11:45:16,690 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] - Last-Modified value for [/hospital/EditWard/HOSP1/] is: -1
2015-03-06 11:45:16,690 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] - Last-Modified value for [/hospital/EditWard/HOSP1/] is: -1
2015-03-06 11:45:16,690 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2015-03-06 11:45:16,690 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2015-03-06 11:45:16,690 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] - Successfully completed request
2015-03-06 11:45:16,690 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] - Successfully completed request
```

This is my controller:

```
package com.freschelegacy.controller;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


import com.freschelegacy.model.Ward;

import com.freschelegacy.model.WardId;
import com.freschelegacy.service.WardService;
import com.freschelegacy.service.data.EditWardDTO;
import com.freschelegacy.service.ServiceException;

import com.freschelegacy.repository.WardRepository;

@RestController()
public class EditWardController {

    @Autowired
    private WardRepository wardRepository;

    @Autowired
    private WardService wardService;

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EditWardController.class);


    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    @RequestMapping(value = "/EditWard", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json;charset=utf-8")
    public Page<EditWardDTO> getEditWard(@PathVariable String hospitalCode, @RequestParam(value= "page", required = false, defaultValue = "0" ) int page, 
                                         @RequestParam(value = "size", required = false, defaultValue = "10"  ) int size){

        Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(page, size);   
        Page<EditWardDTO> pageEditWard = wardRepository.editWard(hospitalCode, pageable);
        return pageEditWard;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added this **/{hospitalCode)** to the value of the @Request mapping. Now it works.

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/EditWard/{hospitalCode}", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json;charset=utf-8")
```